# Tesserocr crashes python

Tags: python, ubuntu, tesseract

I have a problem with "TESSEROCR" python library.
I am using ubuntu 16 (remote connection) , python 3.6, tesseract 4.

I have managed to install it using `PIP` or `CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include pip install tesserocr` method.
However the problem is:
Once I open Python and type: `import tesserocr` python shuts down and I'm back into terminal. I tried to reinstall, build from source and even multiple combination of different versions.

I have no idea where to look for.

Comment: I wanted to try, but I don't manage to install it at all. Sorry.

Comment: Try [`pytesseract`](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract).

Answer (score 0):

When tesserocr is used with Python 3.6 / 3.7 an error arises due to a locale check, the recommend workaround is:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'C')
import tesserocr
```

Further info: https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/issues/137

Answer (score 0):

So there are two problems which I faced while installing Tesserocr library to use System Tesserocr:

1. I needed to install python-dev as the TesserOCR Library has some dependences which are available only in python-dev. `sudo apt install python3-dev`
2. You need to set your locale, for which I used `export LC_ALL=C`.

After activating my virtualenv, I did simply `pip install tesserocr` and it worked like charm.